# Совершенству нет предела?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Цитирую Викисловарь. http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9
Значение слова СОВЕРШЕННЫЙ: 
достигший совершенства, не имеющий недостатков, являющийся безупречным образцом, идеалом чего-либо; полный, абсолютный; 
Синонимы: безупречный, идеальный
Антонимы: небезупречный, неидеальный, несовершенный, дефектный.

Учитывая все это, насколько допустимо употреблять это слово в степенях сравнения: менее/ более совершенный, совершеннее...????
На мой взгляд, это то же, что говорить: более лучший.
Тем не менее, повсеместно употребляется, в частности, в словарях приводятся степени сравнения этого слова.

Answer (score 2):

В настоящее время слово «совершенный» имеет два основных значения, и сравнительная степень ни для одного из них не предусмотрена: 1. Отличающийся совершенством, являющийся совершенством (совершенная красота). 2.  Полный, абсолютный; настоящий, подлинный  (совершенная правда, совершенная темнота).

Употребление степени сравнения извинить здесь никак нельзя, так как во всех случаях, вместо слова совершенный, можно подобрать другие слова, например: более совершенный хватательный навык у ребёнка –  более развитый, более совершенный метод лечения заикания – более эффективный.

Но почему бы нам не пойти навстречу, не увеличить область значения слова?  Думаю, что не стоит этого делать, и  в этом можно убедиться, обратившись к этимологическому словарю.

Глагол совершить восходит к  ст.-сл. слову  «воръхь» – верх. Образовано от «вершить»  (как и завершить). Сейчас вершить мы можем только великие дела, а раньше  крестьяне вершили дом, вершили стог, то есть строили крышу или верхушку стога. Эти события были очень значимыми и торжественно отмечались, поэтому в дальнейшем слово приобрело торжественную окраску и расширило свое значение.

Так что нельзя строить  выше крыши дома, и нельзя быть более совершенным.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ (по ходу дискуссии)

А вдруг всё-таки можно? Ведь если очень долго совершенствоваться, то в конце концов можно усовершенствоваться, то есть стать более совершенным.

Вот и в словарях написано: СОВЕРШЕНСТВОВАТЬСЯ - становиться  лучше, совершеннее; повышать свои знания, мастерство.Но в том же словаре говорится о совершенной красоте как о высшей степени качества.

Чтобы как-то понять ситуацию, попробуем предположить следующее. Прилагательное  "совершенный" может сочетаться с предметами ТОЛЬКО В ОДНОЙ ФОРМЕ: или в форме сравнительной (превосходной) степени, или в обычной форме.

Например, (1)пропорции здания могут быть ТОЛЬКО СОВЕРШЕННЫМИ (сравнительную степень нельзя употребить), а (2) какие-либо методы  совершенными быть в принципе не могут и  употребляются ТОЛЬКО В СРАВНИТЕЛЬНОЙ (ПРЕВОСХОДНОЙ) СТЕПЕНИ (это наиболее совершенный метод лечения, это более совершенная методика).

Таким образом, идеал-абсолют или (1) обозначен (тогда нельзя совершенствоваться и быть совершеннее), или (2)такого предела действительно нет, и можно совершенствоваться до бесконечности, становясь все совершеннее.

Answer (score 2):

Говорят, что совершенству нет предела. Еще есть слово *совершенствование*, указывающее на процесс с постепенной сменой качества. Возможно, с этим и связано представление о совершенстве как о чем-то более или менее выраженном. Если мы что-то совершенствуем, оно становится каким? Сразу совершенным или с более выраженным признаком совершенства? Но это вопрос скорее психологический и философский.

Формально проверочные слова - абсолютный и идеальный. С ними всё просто: ни степеней сравнения, ни процессуальности. Но сочетание "более совершенный" употребляют многие писатели и журналисты. Это слово с особым статусом.

Думаю, когда мы хотим подчеркнуть улучшение чего-то, например имея в виду "более совершенную модель телефона", правильнее говорить "усовершенствованная/улучшенная модель". Смысл передается достаточно точно.

Comment: Кстати, "Словарь синонимов" Тришина фиксирует слово "совершеннее". Действительно, если мы сравниваем два объекта, как спросить "какой из них совершеннее?" по-другому?

Answer (score 2):

С одной стороны, вопрос, конечно интересный... Что такое "более (или менее) совершенный" не совсем понятно, если исходить из определения.

Но с другой, если вспомнить что великий и могучий умудряется образовывать сравнительную степень даже от притяжательных прилагательных (А мой папа папистее твоего!), то уж с качественными прилагательными как-нибудь справится, даже с такими незыблемыми как деревянный или абсолютный.

Значение же в таком случае обычно следует из представления о неполноте соответствия качеству: идеальнее - ближе к идеалу, совершеннее - более близкий к совершенству. И т.д. Последний вариант действительно фиксируется словарями. Причем даже без оговорок, к какому из двух значений (см. София) относится. Т.е. скорее всего - к обоим.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то, полностью согласна с Вами. Как можно быть более или менее совершенным, если совершенство - это уже и так крайняя степень чего бы то ни было. Менее совершенный - это уже НЕ совершенный, а более - просто не может быть.

Answer (score 0):

Так можно говорить любимым людям и они не будут им будет приятно и они не будут копаться в правильности )))

Answer (score 0):

С одной стороны, "совершенство" - это нечто, достигшее вершины, сопутствующее вершине, и нет ничего выше. Выходит, что ни о каком превосходстве не может быть и речи. Но, существует одно слово, дающее повод усомниться в этом, - "усовершенствованный". Цивилизация не стоит на месте, посему, то, что вчера считалось совершенством, сегодня стало усовершенствованным, поэтому и "нет предела совершенству", как и нет предела полёту человеческой мысли.   А вглядываясь  в слово " предел", мыслиться, что оно происходит от "придел" - нечто приделанное, ограничивающие. Разве могут быть ограничения у совершенства?
Можно, конечно, приделать некий стериотип, например, женской красоте, и назвать его пределом совершенству, но это будет чьё-то  сугубо субъективное мнение.

Comment: Совершенные пропорции здания не могут стать более совершенными. Во многих случаях они соответствуют правилу "золотого сечения", когда отношение двух величин равно отношению их суммы к большей из данных величин. (Приблизительная величина золотого сечения равна 1,6180339887). С другой стороны, существует относительное "совершенство" в различных областях науки.